# Identification of a swelling of the lime tree?

Tags: identification

[image: A tree, presumably showing a reaction to being cut down.]

I often see thick, swollen ends of branches on trees in the winter.  The picture shows a "lime tree".

What is this swelling called? How is this caused? Is it caused by the tree being cut down? If so, is this a reaction of... most of trees? Which trees swell like this? Why? **Does it have a name**? Is it damaging to the tree?
Thank you very much.

Comment: where was the picture taken?  In a field of lime trees => an agricultural setting?

Comment: It's where the tree has been pollarded, ie it's where, year after year, young growth has been cut hard back. Try googling ""lime tree" pollarding" and looking at the resultant images.

Comment: @kevinskio It is an image from a graveyard in denmark, Nysogn Churchyard.

Comment: @Peter4075 That's the solution, thanks! Comment it and I can accept your answer, if you care about internet points.

Comment: @Peter4075 please [don’t answer in comments](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), thanks.

Comment: @Stephie - sorry, I've now made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's where the tree has been pollarded, ie it's where, year after year, young growth has been cut hard back. Try googling ""lime tree" pollarding" and looking at the resultant images.